# Don't view layout in "Graphical Layout" tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I created an Android Application Project with a blank Activity, but I don't see anything in the "Graphical Layout Editor".

This is the code in activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error you are seeing in GraphicalEditor?

Comment: What are you expecting really? if you are expecting hello world to show then make sure the hello world string really exist. As it's a blank activity there shouldn't be any hello world string by default

Comment: Although in file activity_main.xml have RelativeLayout but i  don't see RelativeLayout in ""Graphical Layout" tab